# How to remove LUKS encryption after transferring files to an unencrypted disk

Tags: debian, lvm, luks, dm-crypt

My `/` was originally on an encrypted volume and was transferred to an unencrypted volume by recursively copying every directory, and then grub was reinstalled:

```
sudo -s
cp -ax /mnt/encrypted /mnt/decrypted
for f in sys dev proc ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/decrypted/$f ; done
chroot /mnt/decrypted
grub-install /mnt/decrypted
update-grub
```

`/etc/fstab` was updated accordingly and the original encrypted volume was removed from `/etc/crypttab`, but after rebooting I'm still asked for a password to decrypt my new `/`.

Why is that and how can it be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing cryptsetup and regenerating initramfs fixed the problem:

```
apt-get remove --purge cryptsetup
update-initramfs -u -k all
```